# showing data from xml in php in predetermined order

Tags: php, xml

I am still learning how to handle xml data in php,

this is the second part of my previous question [flow control depending on value of xml element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12352300/flow-control-depending-on-value-of-xml-element) .

Now I need to be able to show items in descending or ascending order depending on the "PRICE" tag,

Here is the code so far:

```
<?php
$itm = $_GET['itm'];
$ITEMSS = new SimpleXMLElement('items.xml', null, true);

echo <<<EOF
<table width="100%" align="center" border="1" bordercolor="#0099ff" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="0">

<tr>
        <th bgcolor="#66ccff"><span class="style4">ITEM Name</span></th>
        <th bgcolor="#66ccff"><span class="style4">item TYPE </span></th>
        <th bgcolor="#66ccff"><span class="style4">item DESCIPTION </span></th>
        <th bgcolor="#66ccff"><span class="style4">item PRICE</span></th>
</tr>

EOF;
foreach($ITEMSS as $ITEMS) // loop through our DATAS
{
if($ITEMS->TITLE=="$itm")
{
    echo <<<EOF
    <tr height="30" align=middle>
        <td>{$ITEMS->TITLE}</td>
        <td>{$ITEMS->TYPE}</td>
        <td>{$ITEMS->DESCIPTION}</td>
        <td>{$ITEMS->PRICE}</td>
    </tr>

EOF;
}
}


echo '</table>';
?>
```

Here is the xml tree: http://fast-ptp.fr.cr/xml/items.xml

Here is the page I am testing on:

http://fast-ptp.fr.cr/xml/items.php

Comment: check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1798005/how-to-to-sort-a-xml-feed-with-simplexml

Comment: I tried to understand, but still have problem using paging system and sorting data